# Detect if a web page is using google analytics

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

i have a node server. I pass a Url into request and then extract the contects with cherio. Now what im trying to do is detect if that webpage is using google analytics. How would i do this?

```
request({uri: URL}, function(error, response, body)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        const usesAnalytics = body.includes('googletag') || body.includes('analytics.js') || body.includes('ga.js');
        const isUsingGA = ?;
    }
}
```

From the official analytics site, they say that you can find some strings that would indicate GA is active. I have tried scanning the body for these but they always return false even if that page is running GA. I included this in the code above.

Ive looked at websites that use it and I cant see anything in their index that would suggest they are using it. Its only when i go to their sources and see they are using it. How would i detect this in node?

Comment: *"Ive tried scanning the body for strings but I dont think that works"* - Can you please edit your question to include an example of this? It's much easier for us to help you when we can see what you've tried.

Comment: sure, i added it. @TylerRoper

Comment: If they use async loading, especially with single page application. It's not possible to know just getting the source code. You need to you phantomjs or headless chrome or something similar to render and run the script to make sure if they load the GA.

Comment: Now the latest  GA is using gtag, so you need to check script like `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxx-yy`
Also GA can be included via GTM, so you need to check for `gtm.js` as well.

Comment: To add to the pile of reasons why this isn't going to work, also bear in mind that there are several ways to implement google anlaytics, so there is no catch all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Node script which uses Puppeteer to monitor the requests sent from a website.

I wrote this some time ago so some parts might be irrelevant to you but here you go:

```
'use strict';

 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


function getGaTag(lookupDomain){

 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  (async() => {
        var result = [];
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on('request', request => {

            const url = request.url();
            const regexp = /(UA|YT|MO)-\d+-\d+/i;

            // look for tracking script
            if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/www\.google-analytics\.com\/(r\/)?collect/i)) {

                console.log(url.match(regexp));
                console.log('\n');
                result.push(url.match(regexp)[0]);
            }
            request.continue();
        });

        try {
            await page.goto(lookupDomain);
            await page.waitFor(9000);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Couldn't fetch page " + err);
        }

        await browser.close();
        resolve(result);

    })();

})    

}

getGaTag('https://store.google.com/').then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

Running `node ga-check.js` now returns the UA ID of the Google Analytucs tracker on the lookup domain: `[ 'UA-54090495-1' ]` which in this case is https://store.google.com

Hope this helps!